# Hiding a Slicer for a value from another slicer

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to only **show** a Slicer or a Visual (my main concern is a "ChicletSlicer") when a **specific value** is selected from my **"Date Slicer"**.  And **hide** it when **any other value** selected.

I tried using a Treemap to hide the slicers, but then I cannot use the slicers when I wanted due to Treemap is **over the slicer** (Arranged in front)

Or it should really help if there's a way to conditionally bring forward/backwards any visuals, for selected values.

Comment: At the moment it's not possible to hide or arrange elements dynamically in Power BI. I'm not familiar with Chiclet Slicer, but maybe it's possible to filter the contents of the slicer using visual level filter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can hide a visual from a slicer selection. You can hide always something or try a different approach. The most frecuent use of hide and show is bookmarks with selection pane. Check it out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8vw30ltFJ0

Regards,